# PHP Calculate Total of Looped Items

Tags: php, foreach

I have this code:

```
foreach ($cartContents as $item => $itemQty)
    echo "$item <br /> $itemQty   <br />  $price";
```

It loops through some items and prints the name, quantity and price.  I would then like to print a total of all the prices added together.  Is there a way to get this figure?

Comment: Where/How are you getting $price from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `$itemQty` and `$price` are both numeric, this should work:

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($cartContents as $item => $itemQty) {
    echo "$item <br /> $itemQty   <br />  $price";
    $total += $itemQty * $price;
}

echo "Total: $total<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($cartContents as $item => $itemQty) {
    echo "$item <br /> $itemQty   <br />  $price";
    $total += ($itemQty * $price);
}

echo $total;
```

This doesn't make too much sense as you have no other mention of `$price`

This is also assuming that `$price` is a number rather than a string e.g. `£5.00`

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `$price` variable coming from in your example? Assuming it's valid, then you would simply do this:

```
$totalPrice = 0;
foreach ($cartContents as $item => $itemQty)
{
    echo "$item <br /> $itemQty   <br />  $price";
    $totalPrice += $itemQty * $price;
}

echo $totalPrice ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($cartContents as $item => $itemQty) {
    $total += $price;
    echo "$item <br /> $itemQty   <br />  $price";
}
echo "<br/><br/>Total: $total";
```

I assume that you left out where you're setting the value of `$price` above. This is very basic code; I recommend that you find a simple PHP tutorial to learn basic syntax. There are a million on Google.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $sum=0;
  foreach ($cartContents as $item => $itemQty){

    echo "$item <br /> $itemQty   <br />  $price";
    $sum += $price * $itemQty;

  }

  echo $sum;
```

Answer (score -1):

Set up a variable called $totalprice, and then every loop add the $price to $totalprice. Here's the code, but the synatax is probably wrong, haven't programmed php in a while:

```
//declare variable $totalprice (I forget how)
foreach ($cartContents as $item => $itemQty)
{
echo "$item <br /> $itemQty   <br />  $price";
$totalprice+=$price*$itemQty;
}
```

Edit: Ok, that makes me laugh, 3 people with the same answer at the same time.

Comment: Actually, your solution is subtly - but crucially - different than the other two.

Comment: Oops, forgot item quantity, I'll fix that now.